# Preventing vue2-leaflet map from overlaying itself on top of Vuetify's navigation drawer

Tags: leaflet, navigation-drawer, vuetify.js, z-index

I'm using Vuetify to build an app that displays local points of interest. The app uses [vue2-leaflet](https://vue2-leaflet.netlify.com/) to display the maps. Unfortunately the map pokes out of navigation drawers, dialogs, and darkener screen overlays. Here are images demonstrating it:

[image: Navigation Drawer off - Showing where the map is supposed to be.]
[image: Navigation Draawer on - Map is on top of navigation drawer]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a `z-index` issue. Try adding the following to your CSS:

```css
.v-navigation-drawer--temporary {
    z-index: 1001;
}
```

You can [see a working example on Codepen](https://codepen.io/morphatic/pen/Yzywzqm). I *think* this is the minimum `z-index` value that will get you the overlay that you want, but you may have to play around with it until you get the right value.

NOTE: this solution only works for navigation drawers. You'll probably have to tweak the `z-index` values in custom CSS separately for other types of components like dialogs. Alternatively, you might be able to find where the `z-index` is set in the Leaflet CSS and modify that instead. I'm more familiar with Vuetify so that's what I tweaked.

Comment: I'm uncomfortable with starting a '`z-index` war' when putting UI together. But for now, I guess this is the only solution available.

Comment: Agreed. FWIW, I found this [chrome extension for examining `z-index` values](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/devtools-z-index/bcnpmhefiohkpmjacfoanhbjhikegmoe?hl=en) and this [package for CSS analysis including `z-index`](https://github.com/projectwallace/css-analyzer). Haven't tried them, but at the very least it should make it easier to track down the rules you need to tweak.

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion if z-index needs to be changed: it's better modifying the map itself - rather than Vuetify's css which can affect other components across the app.

In the component where leaflet map is registered add

```
<style lang="scss">
  .vue2leaflet-map {
    z-index: 1;
  }
</style>
```

This works for me using Vuetify + Vue2-leaflet (latest for today's date).
Haven't noticed any issues with other Vuetify components so far.